# Converting an EditText value to string: null value returned

Tags: android, string, android-edittext

I have tried to convert ab EditText value to string, but I don't get the expected result: it shows null...

```
EditText editsignUpUserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editSignUpUserName);
String uName = editsignUpUserName.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Check your `Edittext` name (editSignUpUserName) on your `XML file` it's good

Comment: Or make sure are you using `getText()` after putting value in text filed.

Comment: I agree with @BoradHardik maybe you are getting text in your `onCreate` and you still haven't any text inside `Edittext`

Comment: First, you must check if editsignUpUserName is null because you could be called in a different context. Put more code please...

Comment: I have tried all the above things, i get the input from user,there is no problem in it,but the problem is while converting it to string...i cant find the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleared it,the mistake i have made was converted the edittext to string before even getting the input from user...Complete code given below:

```
EditText editsignUpUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUserName);
signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
String s= editsignUpUserName.getText().toString();
}
```